# How to create a view that can be aligned form its middle?

Tags: android, view, alignment

I created a custom view that is a simple textview under a vertical line. The line is in the center of the view. This is the XML code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/vertBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/TV_date"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/TV_date"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/TV_date"
        >

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/vertical_line"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
    </FrameLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="1337"
        android:id="@+id/TV_date"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The text width can change, and so the important part for alignement is the vertical line.

How can I set the position of this view from the vertical line ?

If this cannot be, is there a workaround to create the same view that could ?

Answer (score 0):

Here this will solve your problem i hope.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/vertBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/TV_date"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/TV_date"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/TV_date"
        >

        <View
            android:layout_width="1dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/vertical_line"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>
    </FrameLayout>
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:text="1337"
        android:id="@+id/TV_date"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. If you try to concatenate some in an horizontal linearlayout, you'll end with only one view inside... But it's still a hint, thanks !